# Simple OpenMP program for detecting GPU and other devices does not work

Tags: gcc, gpu, openmp, nvidia

I'm trying to write a very simple example with OpenMP using GCC 12 as compiler and the `target` clause in order to detect all my devices, but it does not work. First of all, I have a Lenovo W540 running Debian Sid with an integrated Inted HD Graphics 4600 (which is the GPU the GUI -plasma- is using). Also, there is a NVIDIA GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M]. I have installed the `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-390xx`, `nvidia-legacy-390xx-driver`, and `nvidia-legacy-390xx-kernel-dkms` packages, as they are the corresponding drivers for my GPU. Running the `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` command I obtain

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Lenovo 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Lenovo GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M]
        Kernel modules: nvidia
```

so I suppose that the NVDIA GPU is well configured and detected. Am I right?

Then, I borrowed this simply code from https://enccs.github.io/openmp-gpu/target/

```
/* Copyright (c) 2019 CSC Training */
/* Copyright (c) 2021 ENCCS */
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif

int main() 
{
  int num_devices = omp_get_num_devices();
  printf("Number of available devices %d\n", num_devices);

  #pragma omp target 
  {
      if (omp_is_initial_device()) {
        printf("Running on host\n");    
      } else {
        int nteams= omp_get_num_teams(); 
        int nthreads= omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("Running on device with %d teams in total and %d threads in each team\n",nteams,nthreads);
      }
  }
  
}
```

Compilation with GCC as `gcc -Wall -fopenmp example.c -o example` works fine and does not produce warnings nor errors, but at execution time I obtain simply

```
Number of available devices 0
Running on host
```

so not Inter nor NVIDIA GPUs were detected. Inspecting the Debian repositories I've seen and installed the packages `gcc-offload-nvptx`, `gcc-12-offload-nvptx`, `libgomp-plugin-nvptx1`, and `nvptx-tools`. Now, when I compile again as `gcc -Wall -fopenmp example.c -o example` I obtain a warning:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccrWP8gn.crtoffloadtable.o: warning: relocation against `__offload_vars_end' in read-only section `.rodata'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
```

When I execute the code I obtain again

```
Number of available devices 0
Running on host
```

but in this case the execution is terrubly slow (various seconds of time).
Searching the web I've seen that I must add the option `-foffload=nvptx-none` to the compilation order, but I obtain the same results as previously (this option only is recognized if `gcc-offload-nvptx` et al. are installed.

Running `gcc -v` I can see that GCC 12 in Debian is configured for offloading:

```
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I don't know which number is my NVIDIA card, but I've tried `export OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=0` and `export OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=2` with the same wrong result of

```
Number of available devices 0
Running on host
```

So, how can I run my OpenMP code in the GPU?

Thanks